# Still detecting element when its not there

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-secondary btn-buy add-cart')[0];

function autoSearch() {
  if(typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null){
    console.log('Element DOES Exist');
  }
  else {
    console.log('Element Does NOT Exist!');
  }
}
```

my goal for it is to detect if an element exists and respectively execute a function if it exists or not. When the element does NOT exist, it is under the Class Name `btn btn-secondary btn-buy add-cart hidden` but when it DOES exist it is under the Class Name `btn btn-secondary btn-buy add-cart`.

When I detect if `btn btn-secondary btn-buy add-cart` exists, it still says that it exists when its still hidden. I suspect it is because `btn btn-secondary btn-buy add-cart hidden` has the exact lettering with the element when it does exist but I am not sure how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As a general debugging rule, when you experience an unexpected result like this just print the tested value: `console.log (typeof(element) `. You would have found what type was missing.

Comment: Hidden elements are still in document, these are just not visible. That's why your selector still matches.

Answer (score 0):

better approach is to simply check for hidden class

```
if (document.getElementById("yourId").classList.contains('hidden')) {
   //do smh if you have a hidden class
}else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by either check if the element is hidden or not, or only select when it's not hidden:

First way:

```
const el = document.querySelector(".btn.btn-secondary.btn-buy.add-cart:not(.hidden)");

if (el) {
    // Do something when it's not hidden
} else {
    // It's hidden
}
```

Second way, in this case, your `el` will always have value (assume the element is there always):

```
const el = document.querySelector(".btn.btn-secondary.btn-buy.add-cart");

if (el.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    // Do something when it's not hidden
} else {
    // It's hidden
}
```